# kernel: Can preemption occur while do_fork() is executing?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kernel

Is do_fork() safe from preemption? In other words, can the parent process allocate a new task struct and then get preempted, before getting a chance to insert the new task struct into the ready queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not safe from preemption.

The `do_fork` calls `copy_process` which in turn does the `sched_fork` that initializes the task. Afterwards the `do_fork` calls `wake_up_new_task` in order to put it on the run queue.

This is separated in order to be able to kill or terminate a process before being scheduled.

The `sched_fork` disables preemption, but enables it once its done with its work, making it possible for the kernel to preempt before calling the `wake_up_new_task` and putting it on the run queue.

This is based on my knowledge of the 2.6 kernel.